# Slicing longitude coordinate in xarray which crosses the 0

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have xarray dataset with longitude coordinate from 0.5 to 359.5, like the following:

```
Dimensions:    (bnds: 2, lat: 40, lev: 35, lon: 31, member_id: 1)
Coordinates:
    lev_bnds   (lev, bnds) float64 ...
    lon_bnds   (lon, bnds) float64 ...
    lat_bnds   (lat, bnds) float64 ...
  * lon        (lon) float64 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 ... 359.5
  * lev        (lev) float64 2.5 10.0 20.0 32.5 ... 5e+03 5.5e+03 6e+03 6.5e+03
  * lat        (lat) float64 -89.5 -88.5 -87.5 -86.5 ... -53.5 -52.5 -51.5 -50.5
  * member_id  (member_id) object 'r1i1p1f1'
Dimensions without coordinates: bnds
Data variables:
    so         (member_id, lev, lat, lon) float32 nan nan nan ...
```

The area I'm interested in is between 60W to 30E, which probably corresponds to longitude 300.5 to 30.5. Is there any way to slice the dataset between these coordinates?
I tried to use `isel(slice(-60,30)` but it's not possible to have negative to positive numbers in the slice function.
I know I can just split the data into two small ones (300.5-359.5 and 0.5-30.5), but I was wondering if there is a better way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly point out, currently `isel` can’t select from both the start and end of a dimension in a single pass.

If combined with `roll`  http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.roll.html, you can move the points you want into a contiguous region, and then select those you need.

NB: I couldn’t be sure from your example, but it looks like you may want `sel` rather than `isel`, given you may be selecting by index value rather than position